# How to create a new System account on Sharepoint 2010/2013 that can access file on all sites?

Tags: permissions, web-services

I've been using a local admin account to access all the files on my sharepoint sites. it's working fine.

But best practices say don't do that. they say to create a system account to crawl with instead.

So i created an active directory system account instead. and then to configure that system account such that it can get permission to everything.

But now I only can see metadata. anyone know why that might happen? What permissions screen should i go into to change this?

Answer (score 1):

The search crawl account should only have Full Read permissions and no more.  Grant the access to the account via the Web App's User Policy so that it applies to all site collections within as that policy cannot be overridden lower down.

Normally when you configure the default crawl account, the user policies are set automatically but not always.